# How can I display a forreach() list of div on multiple three columns row

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I display an array `posts:[]`, which contain a `JSON` object. Everything is fine except that I can't display three columns in a row with Bootstrap. Even though I specified in the class="col-4". Here's my code.

```
    <div class="" v-for="post of posts">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
        <router-link :to="'panneau/' + post['id_panneau']">
       "...."   
        </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: The following image shows what it happens and how I want it to act]

Comment: Can you please post screenshot for the issue. Btw you need to add class `row` to the parent div containing columns.

Comment: I added the screenshot you asked for. I do know that I need to place a row but I don't know where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code as given below and check:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" v-for="post of posts">
      <router-link :to="'panneau/' + post['id_panneau']">
         "...."   
      </router-link>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The v-for="..." property must be in the element you want to loop. In this case you are looping the first div not the one with the col-* class. Try remove the second div and add those classes to the first one.

```
<div  class="col-12 col-lg-4" v-for="post of posts">
    <router-link :to="'panneau/' + post['id_panneau']">
      "...."   
    </router-link>
</div>
```